# Decimal to Binary conversion for even numbers wrong output in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I am having below code to convert DEC to BIN and then reverse it and then convert back to DEC.

I am getting correct results when I pass ODD numbers but for EVEN numbers it is not accurate.

Could someone help me what I am doing wrong?

```js
  function mirror_bits(n) {
        var NumFromInvNum = parseInt(n.toString(2).split("").reverse().join(""), 2);
         return NumFromInvNum;
    }
console.log(mirror_bits(2031768448)); 
console.log(mirror_bits(3105510272)); 
console.log(mirror_bits(622482304)); 
console.log(mirror_bits(3357168512));
```

Example values I am seeing issue are

Input = 2031768448 | expected output = 30038174 -- not working

Input = 3105510272 | expected output = 30038173 -- working

Input = 622482304 | expected output = 30038180 -- not working

Input = 3357168512 | expected output = 30038035 -- working

Input = 1562006400 | expected output = 30038202-- not working

Input = 3709490048 | expected output = 30038203-- not working

Comment: Thanks for making a code snippet, but it does not do anything. Also, there seems to be a problem with the local variable names in the function.

Comment: Sure, edited the question.

Comment: Your expected outputs indicate that you're treating your numbers as 32-bit numbers. But if the input is smaller than `2**31` then you don't pad the result of the binary conversion with extra zeros on the left to make it up to length `32`. That's why your code is working for inputs of `2**31` or larger, but not for values smaller than `2**31`. (As an extreme case, consider what happens if your input is `1`. Extrapolating from your expected outputs, you'd expect the output in that case to be `2147483648`, but your code will create and reverse a string of `"1"`, giving an output of `1` again.)

Comment: Can you help in modifying my code to accomodate that?

Comment: You are not passing odd numbers, all your inputs are even.

Comment: Correct, odd/even was for my outputs sorry, I had thought that way. But Mark's explaination makes sense, just need to know how to accomodate that in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing any issues with the code. Maybe if you keep track of each transformation of the process, you can track down why you are getting unexpected output?

Odd numbers always have a `1` as their least-significant bit. This mean, that if reversed, the `1` will become the most-significant bit. Depending on number of bits, this leading `1` could be interpreted as a signed bit. I am not seeing any negative numbers in the output below.

Also, what is your expected output for your odd numbers you have above?

In the snippet below, I return an object with the decimal, binary, reverse binary, and reverse decimal values.

### Update 1

After reviewing your updated question, your input does not produce your expected output. After aligning the binary digits, it looks like you are shifting to the left by 1-2 digits and filling in the least-significant bits with `0`. I am not sure why you expect the output that you have stated above?

```js
const mirrorBits = (dec) => {
  const bin = dec.toString(2);
  const binRev = bin.split('').reverse().join('');
  const decRev = parseInt(binRev, 2);
  return { dec, decRev, bin, binRev };
};

console.log(mirrorBits(2031768448)); // See #1 ~ 15019087
console.log(mirrorBits(3105510272)); // 30038173
console.log(mirrorBits(622482304));  // See #3 ~ 7509545
console.log(mirrorBits(3357168512)); // 30038035
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!--

in = 2031768448 | expected = 30038174 -- not working
in = 3105510272 | expected = 30038173 -- working
in = 622482304  | expected = 30038180 -- not working
in = 3357168512 | expected = 30038035 -- working


#1
Actual    : 0000000111001010010110001001111  (15019087)
Expected? :        1110010100101100010011110 (30038174) << 1

#3
Actual    : 000000011100101001011000101001   (7509545)
Expected? :        1110010100101100010100100 (30038180) << 2

-->
```

### Update 2

You need to pad (32 bits; aka 4 byte integer) your original binary value with zeroes before reversing.

i.e. `dec.toString(2).padStart(32, '0');`

```js
const mirrorBits = (dec) => {
  const bin = dec.toString(2).padStart(32, '0');
  const binRev = bin.split('').reverse().join('');
  const decRev = parseInt(binRev, 2);
  return { dec, decRev, bin, binRev };
};

console.log(mirrorBits(2031768448)); // 30038174
console.log(mirrorBits(3105510272)); // 30038173
console.log(mirrorBits(622482304));  // 30038180
console.log(mirrorBits(3357168512)); // 30038035
console.log(mirrorBits(1562006400)); // 30038202
console.log(mirrorBits(3709490048)); // 30038203
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Additionally, you could use an online number converter e.g. [RapidTables - Binary to Decimal converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html) to compare your results.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with input and expected output values. Thanks.

Comment: so that is my output I need to produce. because the conversion actually takes place on the backend using TAL program. I need to rewrite it in JavaScript. is there a piece of code that you can update for the above code to do the expected output I need? Thanks much

Comment: Also, I have another example of even number 2635748224 this one works fine. Not sure what the code is checking for?

Comment: 1562006400 --- 30038202 -- not working

3709490048 --- 30038203 -- not working

Few more samples, do you see any pattern why these are failing in javaScript

Comment: @user2390526 ok, Mark made a fair point. Please check the suggestion in the 2nd update above.